# changing object array data

Tags: c++, class

I have two objects deck.h and cards.h

now in the object class we have an object array created (theDeck[card_Num];)

at this point we have an array with 52 card objects, but from my understanding we have 52 cards with no value.

my question is how can i give the values to each card without having to make a setter in the class file?

i had thought it was something like this theDeck[i].card(faceVale, suite::type)
in the deck constructor but i kept getting an error mostly because am wrong

```
class Deck
{
  public:
  // default constructor
  Deck();
  private:
  static const int Card_Num = 52; //Max # of cards in  a deck
  Card    theDeck[Card_Num];    // the array holding the cards
  int     topCard;              // the index of the top card on the deck
};
```

cards.h object

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

enum suite {clubs, hearts, spades, diamonds};

class Card
{
  public:
   //default constructor. It is required since another class
   //may declare an array of Card objects.
   Card();

   //another constructor
   Card (int faceValue, suite type);

   // return the point value
   int getPointValue() const;

  private:
    suite   type;       // the suite of the card
    int     faceValue;   // the face value of the card
    int     pointValue;      // the point value of the card, it is a derived        value

};
```

Comment: _"without having to make a setter in the class file?"_ Of which class specifically?

Comment: in the cards.h file

Comment: It would be a good idea to [edit] your question to remove the irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i give the values to each card without having to make a setter in the class file?

Since you have declared this `public` constructor for `Card`

```
Card (int faceValue, suite type);
```

you can use an initializer list in `Deck`'s constructor:

```
 Deck::Deck() : theDeck { { 1, clubs }, { 2, clubs }, ... { 13, clubs }
                        , { 1, hearts }, { 2, hearts }, ... { 13, hearts }
                        ...
                        , { 1, diamonds }, { 2, diamonds }, ... { 13, diamonds } }
 {
 }
```

---

> at this point we have an array with 52 card objects, but from my understanding we have 52 cards with no value.

In fact you should even `delete` your default constructor

```
 Card() = delete;
```

because it doesn't make sense semantically. There isn't such thing like a card without a face and a value.

---

Alternatively you could reassign the default constructed `Card` values in the constructor body like this:

```
Deck::Deck() {
    int i = 0;
    for(auto& card : theDeck) {
        int faceValue = i%13 + 1;
        if(i < 13) {
           card = Card(faceValue,clubs);
        }
        else if(i < 26) {
           card = Card(faceValue,hearts);
        }
        else if(i < 39) {
           card = Card(faceValue,spades);
        }
        else if(i < 52) {
           card = Card(faceValue,diamonds);
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain more about this

Comment: @William What don't you understand specifically?

Comment: shouldnt i only be allowed to pick the array index like theDeck[i].... i didnt know u could enter information into an array like that

Comment: so each curl bracket represents the position in the array?

Comment: @William Yes. And it's done at initialization of `Deck`. Don't confuse the _positions_ with the 1st _`faceValue`_ parameter. I used counting from 1-13, as usual for card decks.

Comment: can i put a loop in it?

Comment: @William _"can i put a loop in it?"_ Regarding the initializer list with some template trickery may be. But what I proposed is the most basic way. Since you have default assignment and copy constuctors, you can also overwrite the default constructed values in the array in a loop

Comment: i got that part its just i didn't really know you could do that .. thanks i appreciate the help

Comment: @William I've added some more elaboration regarding the loop.